# ios can't change the position of a subview when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, position, subview

I am new to iOS. I added a textField with a tag = -125 using storyboard in the middle of the screen and linked it to an outlet. I want to move it up a little bit when the keyboard appears.

The code below changes its background color to green, but it does not change its position!

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews){
            if(subView.tag == -125){ //the tag of my textfield. using self.myTextField gave same results
                subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];     //this works fine!!
                subView.frame = CGRectMake(subView.frame.origin.x, subView.frame.origin.y - 50, subView.frame.size.width, subView.frame.size.height);       //this does not work!! does not move!
            }
        }
    }];
}


//i don't do anything now in keyboardWillHide


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

I have positioned it in the middle of the screen to see if its position changes when the keyboard is up or not. It does not change. The background changes to green!

Comment: Do you have any autolayout constraints on that view?

Comment: it sure sounds like there are auto layout constraints in your way.  In IB, under the file inspector (first icon in the group at upper right), see if "Use Auto Layout is checked".

Comment: OMG! That was an easy fix. I have been looking around for more than an hour! Thanks :)